# Error: unknown signer: 149J5z7P1MLvbUMepVf2DCxESoRPN5cQHFdA7dwCW121

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

```
async function createCounter() {
    const provider = getProvider();

    if (!provider) {
        console.error('Provider is not available');
        return;
    } 
    if (!baseAccount || !baseAccount.publicKey) {
        console.log('Error: baseAccount or publicKey is missing.');
        return;
    }

    if (!web3.SystemProgram.programId) {
        console.log('Error: SystemProgram programId is missing.');
        return;
    }
    // Get the connected Phantom wallet's public key
    const connectedPublicKey = provider.wallet.publicKey;
    const contract = JSON.stringify(idl);
    const instance = JSON.parse(contract);
    const program = new Program(instance, idl.metadata.address, provider);
    try {
        console.log("baseAccount",baseAccount)
        console.log(baseAccount.publicKey)
        const init = await program.rpc.initialize(1, {
            accounts: {
                authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                pool: baseAccount.publicKey,
                vault: baseAccount.publicKey,
                owner: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                poolSigner: connectedPublicKey,
                systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
            },
            signers: [baseAccount],
        });

        console.log('Pool Initialized:', init);
        const account = await program.account.myAccount.fetch(baseAccount.publicKey);
        console.log('account: ', account);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Transaction error: ", err);
    }
}
```

Transaction error:  Error: unknown signer: 149J5z7P1MLvbUMepVf2DCxESoRPN5cQHFdA7dwCW121

facing this issue while initilize smart contract

Here is my account struct

```
[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(nonce: u8)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    /// CHECK
    pub authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    owner: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        seeds = [
            pool.to_account_info().key.as_ref(),
        ],
        bump = nonce,
    )]
    /// CHECK
    pool_signer: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    /// CHECK
    pool: Box<Account<'info, Pool>>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            pool.to_account_info().key.as_ref(),
        ],
        bump = nonce,
    )]
    /// CHECK
    vault: AccountInfo<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your accounts struct the only expected signer is owner: `owner: Signer<'info>`

When you call this you pass the connected wallet as the owner: `owner: provider.wallet.publicKey`

But then you pass a different account called baseWallet as the signer: `signers: [baseAccount]`. You're passing that as the pool and vault, neither of which are signers on the instruction. This baseWallet is probably `149J5z7P1MLvbUMepVf2DCxESoRPN5cQHFdA7dwCW121`.

You should be able to pass `provider.wallet` as the signer instead, which is the account expected to sign the transaction.

Comment: Thanks. It worked!

Comment: Getting this issue now:

Transaction error: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x92 at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (connection.ts:5921:1) at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (connection.ts:5880:1) at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:84:1) at async w.send (provider.ts:124:1) at async Object.initialize (rpc.ts:26:1) at async createCounter (App.tsx:111:1)

Comment: Please create a separate question if you're having a separate issue